# Php этапы выполнения программы

Tags: php7

Как происходят этапы выполнения программы? (парсер компилятор и рантайм)

Comment: Гугл в помощь, найти информацию не так сложно.Чтобы хорошо понять узнать советую изучать одну тему по разным источникам.
habr.com - думаю поможет во многом

Comment: https://habr.com/company/mailru/blog/304748/

Comment: @ЗунЗунов Пожалуйста, [не отправляйте спрашивающих в поисковики](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2013/213987)